# Can I use cron for curl realted works?

Tags: php, cron

Here is my situation.

I have a ubuntu web server and I have a million domain names in my server mysql database.

My php script uses curl multi option to get the data. I have a foreach loop. In every loop 10 domains are queried from the database and then passed it to curl. Returned data get stored in the database.

As of now I connected to the server using ubuntu terminal ( ssh )

I'm executing my php script from that terminal `php myfile.php`

I'm getting output like success/Failure for each domain in the terminal..

Now I would like to shutdown my PC. But if I shutdown my PC, then the script execution will be stopped.

To overcome this problem, I would like to run the script automatically using cron.

Please note: It takes around 10 seconds to finish 10 domains. So to complete million domains It will take atleast 10 days. Once the script started it needs 10 days to stop.

So my question is "Can I use cron in this situation?".

Comment: Each run represents 10 domains that will be queried?

Comment: you could use cron, but you don't need to, scripts called from the command line have no time limit. of course noting will get around, shutting down the server will stop it.

Comment: If your script needs to be able to resume automagically you could use cron.

Comment: @leon Yes. Each run, I get 10 domains from the database like this. `"SELECT domain FROM mytable WHERE status = NULL LIMIT 10"`

Comment: @Dagon As I said in my question, I want to shut down my PC. Because I cannot run my PC for 10 days without shutting it down.

Comment: @Jack "resume automatically?" I don't get it. Its a simple script. All I just have to do is open the script either in brower or using terminal. It can be stoped only if I cancel the script execution

Comment: is the server on your pc?

Comment: @Dagon No I have a real hosting web server.

Comment: then i dont understand what your pc has to do with it

Comment: @Dagon I use SSH to connect to the server. Executing that php script from the ssh terminal. Because if I run it in the browser, then the browser will crash. Script will run as long as I leave that terminal open. If I close the terminal, then the execution will be stopped.

Comment: ok some basic *nix `nohup php myfile.php &` hope your on a dedicated machine, no shared host is going to allow this

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server you can use cron on, tweak the script to run in under one minute, call it every minute using cron and let the server handle it. You'll need to ensure processed rows are marked as such so that the script doesn't overlap with a previous run (or with an interrupted one).